# SQLAlchemy JSON TypeDecorator not saving correctly, issues with session.commit()

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

My models.py file has two models, User and Job.

Each job will have multiple Users associated with it.

A user can be associated with multiple jobs.

I need to be able to do something like job.getUsers() --> list of User objects

I tried to use TypeDecorators to store a JSON int array in my Job table. Each int represents a User's pk, which I can later use to find the correct row in the db.

At first glance, this was working fine, but I'm getting some weird bugs (bottom of post, after my code).

```
class Json(TypeDecorator):

    impl = String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return json.loads(value)


class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date)
    workers = Column(Json(128))

    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = []
```

Here is my weird output

```
>>> db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))

>>> job = Job()
>>> job.workers
[]
>>> job.workers.append(1)
>>> job.workers
[1]
>>> db_session.add(job)
>>> job.workers
[1]
>>> db_session.commit()
>>> job.workers
[1]
>>> job = Job.query.filter(Job.id == 1).first()
>>> job.workers
[1]
```

At this point, it looks like everything ok. When I try adding a second item to the list, things start to go wrong.

```
>>> job.workers.append(2) # let's try adding another item to the list.
>>> job.workers
[1, 2]
>>> db_session.add(job) # is this necessary? added for debugging purposes, seems to have no effect on anything
>>> job.workers
[1, 2]
>>> db_session.commit() # autoflush is on
>>> job.workers
[1] # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??????????????????????/
```

Please let me know if you have any idea what I'm doing wrong. Alternatively, let me know if there is a better way to do this instead of a JSON TypeDecorator. Thanks!

Comment: Please see this MutableDict recipe if you want to nested changes automatically to propagate in SQLAlchemy http://variable-scope.com/posts/mutation-tracking-in-nested-json-structures-using-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 19):

SQLAlchemy has issues persisting JSON that's been updated. I had this exact same frustrating issue but found the answer here :

https://bashelton.com/2014/03/updating-postgresql-json-fields-via-sqlalchemy/

In summary, use 'flag_modified' method from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified    

jobs.workers.append(2)
flag_modified(jobs, "workers")
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Allen, can you add a summary of the answer from the link reference? It helps your answer remain useful in case of the link breaking.

Comment: Please see this MutableDict recipe if you need to deal with nested dictionary and lists in Python http://variable-scope.com/posts/mutation-tracking-in-nested-json-structures-using-sqlalchemy

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa your link is broken. Best to post the info in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, seems SQLAlchemy's update won't be executed if json filed is of the same id in python.

So my solution is to assign a new object to json filed. Below codes should work:

```
job.workers = job.workers + [2, ]
db_session.add(job)
db_session.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I got around this by copying the data first:

```
import copy

workers = copy.deepcopy(job.workers)
workers.append(2)
job.workers = workers
```

I used [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html), because my data is a more complex object.

Comment: I tried with `deepcopy` but no success. Can see nested data even after `.add(<var>)` operation but not after `.commit()`

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict # <--- !

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class SomeModel(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
data = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(db.JSON)) # <--- !
```